# javascript max size

Tags: javascript

I have a local html-site (on CD, memory stick or disk). In this site I perform extensive search operations which need a lot of data, about 10 MB. Storing the data in HTML-code and keeping them invisibly works, but makes loading very slow (presumably because of the parsing time needed by the browser).

An alternative are javascript objects in .js-files. But I found with different browsers (FF, Opera, Safari), if a javascript file has more than 100 KB, the data are no more recognized. This size is far insufficient for my case. Is there a possibility to extend that limit?

Comment: "But I found with different browsers (FF, Opera, Safari), if a javascript file has more than 100 KB, the data are no more recognized" Never heard about that. The size of uncompressed jQuery source file, for example, is 242 kb. Another js file in one of the Webmail interfaces I was modifying one time had to be 120 kb. And everything was working fine. Could you give a link to the example?

Answer (score 0):

Dirty hack, but you can just place your objects to the some directory in json files and call them via ajax calls from local drive (didn't tried at ie's, but it works great from FF and Chrome)